# Recursive t-sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as shown below.

```
ID ParentID Node Name  Node Type
------------------------------------------------------------------
525 524  Root   Area Level 1
526 525  C   Area Level 2
527 525  A   Area Level 2
528 525  D   Area Level 2
671 525  E   Area Level 2
660 527  B   Area Level 3
672 671  F   Area Level 3
```

How can i write a recursive t-sql query to generate below output?

Output ("Root" node not required in the output):

```
Node  ID
-----------------------
A  527
A/B  660
C  526
D  528
E  671
E/F  672
```

Thanks

Comment: And will you only need two levels or could there be data where a relates to b relates to c?

Comment: sql server 2005. There could be more than 2 levels

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(SQL.90).aspx) on using common table expressions.  That is what I would use (assuming you are using at least SQL Server 2005)

Here is a code example using your case:

```
 WITH CTE (NodePath, ID) AS (
    SELECT
        '/' + CAST(NodeName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NodePath,
        ID
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE NodeName = 'Root'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        CTE.NodePath + '/' + CAST(NodeName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS NodePath,
        TABLE.ID
    FROM CTE
    INNER JOIN TABLE ON TABLE.ParentId = CTE.ID
)

SELECT
    NodeName,
    ID
FROM CTE
```

Comment: @Gabriel, +1, I just wrote same sample code to update my previous answer =)

Comment: is it possible i can do something like "SELECT  NodeName, ID FROM CTE" some way to pass level value to this

Answer (score 0):

Recursion in SQL for SQL Server is described and demontrated here:

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=sqlserver&seqNum=90

And here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=366078

and here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could also to take a look on [Common Table Expressions (CTE) in SQL Server 2005](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml)