# SQL recursive CTE query, odd results set SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I am trying to write a recursive CTE query in SQL Server 2005 but am getting an odd set of results.  My table is:

```
PairID  ChildID ParentID
900        1        2       
901        2        3       
902        3        4
```

This is my CTE Query:

```
WITH TESTER (PairID, 
             ChildID, 
             ParentID, 
             Level)
AS (SELECT a.PairID, a.ChildID,a.ParentID, 0 AS Level
    FROM BusinessHierarchy AS a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT b.PairID, b.ChildID, b.ParentID, oh.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM BusinessHierarchy AS b INNER JOIN
    TESTER AS oh ON b.ChildID =  oh.ParentID)
SELECT 
      x.PairID, 
      x.ChildID,
      x.ParentID,
      x.Level
 FROM TESTER AS x
 ORDER BY x.Level, x.ChildID, x.ParentID
```

Ok, so I am now getting a dataset return, however, it is not as expected in that it contains repetition in the following manner:

```
PairID  ChildID ParentID Level
900     1       2        0
901     2       3        0
902     3       4        0
...

900     2       3        1
901     3       4        1
...

900     3       4        2
```

If someone could explain to me why this is happening and how I would could correct it I would be very grateful.

As far as my last question goes, how would I have to modify it to display the initial childID with each of the parents like this:

```
Original
PairID  ChildID ParentID Level
900     1       2        0
901     2       3        1
902     3       4        2

I want it displayed as:
PairID  ChildID ParentID Level
900     1       2        0
901     1       3        1
902     1       4        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your starting point.  The first part of the CTE query returns all rows (notice their level is all 0).

Then - Your next part of the query will go and get all the related rows (which adds to your earlier resultset).

I did notice, however, that you have no record for the id of 4

if you did, here is what you would do:

```
;WITH TESTER (PairID, ChildID, ParentID, Level) AS (
    SELECT
        a.PairID,
        a.ChildID,
        a.ParentID,
        0 AS Level
    FROM BusinessHierarchy AS a
    LEFT JOIN BusinessHierarchy a2 ON a.ParentID = a2.ChildID
    WHERE a2.PairID is null

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        b.PairID,
        b.ChildID,
        b.ParentID,
        oh.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM BusinessHierarchy AS b
    INNER JOIN TESTER AS oh ON b.ParentID =  oh.ChildID
)

SELECT 
    x.PairID, 
    x.ChildID,
    x.ParentID,
    x.Level
FROM TESTER AS x
ORDER BY x.Level, x.ChildID, x.ParentID
```

Also, see [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023897/recursive-t-sql-query/2023954#2023954) to show the correct sort order (using the path)

Comment: I ran the query but get no results.  I think the problem is the 'parentId is null' which is why I emitted it from my version.  I have read several forums and versions/examples and just don't see why this doesn't work.

Comment: my code assumed that you would add a record with an id of 4.  If you're not, you have to have a starting point some other way.

Comment: See my modified answer that will work in your case (I joined back to the table to see where there was no child record).

Comment: Is @tbl supposed to be BusinessHierarchy again?  @tbl throws an error and BusinessHierarchy returns the wrong data.  @tbl is a temporary table isn't it?  Is there another way of achieving this?

I also ran some test data with a record for 4 with null as the parent and now I see what you mean in that it worked perfectly.

Comment: Yeah.  Sorry.  cut and paste error.  @tbl should be BusinessHierarchy.

Comment: @flavour: That was a paste error.  I modified my answer already.

Comment: Ok, that is great but I am going to ask a couple of daft questions.  1) How do I change the level assignment around so that the lowest level starts at 0 and the highest level is, in this exmaple 2? 2) How do you group them together, so for example lets say that I wanted to put in childID = 1 (or 90937) and I would have the hierarchy for that group displayed?

Thanks, this has really been a great help.

Comment: 1) by changing your starting point (the first part of the CTE query).  for example, "where childid = 1"  and then modify the join to get parent instead of child. -  2) modify the where clause so that you're using a variable (like "where childid = @variable")

Comment: OK, one final question, how do you display the lowest level child ID rather than the subsequent higher up ones?  I put an example of what I mean at the top, but lets just say that my first child id is 1, that child id would be displayed as the childID for each level?

Comment: I actually managed to achieve everything I wanted with this, including reversing the levels and also the childID display.  I wouldn't have been able to do it without your guidance, so thanks, it was great.

Comment: Not a problem.  I'm glad I was able to help.